# Assertion error in a simple C++ program using boost:odeint

Tags: c++, boost, odeint

I'm sorry if this is immediately obvious, but I am very new to C++ coming from a Python / MATLAB / Mathematica background. I've written a simple solver for the classic 1D heat equation using a finite difference spatial discretization in order to play around with the capabilities of the [Odeint](http://headmyshoulder.github.io/odeint-v2/) library and compare the performance with other libraries. The code should be quite self-explanatory:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/math/constants/constants.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/odeint.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost::numeric::odeint;

const double a_sq = 1;
const int p = 10;
const double h = 1 / p;

double pi = boost::math::constants::pi<double>();

typedef boost::array<double, p> state_type;


void heat_equation(const state_type &x, state_type &dxdt, double t)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<p; i++)
    {
        dxdt[i] = a_sq * (dxdt[i+1] - 2*dxdt[i] + dxdt[i-1]) / h / h;
    }     
    dxdt[0] = 0;
    dxdt[p] = 0;
}

void initial_conditions(state_type &x)
{
   int i;
   for (i=0; i<=p; i++)
   {
      x[i] = sin(pi*i*h);
   }
}

void write_heat_equation(const state_type &x, const double t)
{
   cout << t << '\t' << x[0] << '\t' << x[p] << '\t' << endl;
}

int main()
{
    state_type x;
    initial_conditions(x);    
    integrate(heat_equation, x, 0.0, 10.0, 0.1, write_heat_equation);
}
```

This compiles just fine on Ubuntu 14.04 using g++ 4.8.2 and the latest boost library from the Ubuntu repository. When I run the resulting executable, however, I get the following error:

```
***** Internal Program Error - assertion (i < N) failed in T& boost::array<T, N>::operator[](boost::array<T, N>::size_type) [with T = double; long unsigned int N = 10ul; boost::array<T, N>::reference = double&; boost::array<T, N>::size_type = long unsigned int]:
/usr/include/boost/array.hpp(123): out of range
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Unfortunately, this isn't particularly helpful to my novice brain and I'm at a loss as to how to fix this. What's causing the error?

Comment: In `write_heat_equation` you access `x[p]`, but the last valid index is `p-1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Counting the elements of an array or a vector of N-elements start by zero. The last element has index N-1. So, you need to change your for-loop to iterate from i to p-1 and you need to modify the line dxdt[p] = 0; to dxdt[p-1] = 0:

```
for (i=1; i<p-1; i++)
{
    dxdt[i] = a_sq * (dxdt[i+1] - 2*dxdt[i] + dxdt[i-1]) / h / h;
}     
dxdt[0] = 0;
dxdt[p-1] = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, making the corrections you suggested as well as one in the write_heat_equation function it now works as intended. I apologize for wasting your time with such a trivial question.